# CircularProgressIndicator widget doesn't disappear when image loads

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using this dart package [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/transparent_image)
There's an example in the [flutterio](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) cookbook. My problem is, when the image loads the CircularProgressIndicator doesn't disappear. Here is the item for a ListView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
import 'models/post.dart';

class PostItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const PostItem(this.post);

  final Post post;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
              )),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                    placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                    image: post.imageUrl,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(
            post.username,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(
            post.text,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

A gif of the problem:

[image]

My understanding is, that once the image loads the CircularProgressIndicator should disappear?

Comment: I am guessing that it is because it is in a stateless widget so the stack repaint is not triggered. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) plugin

```
new CachedNetworkImage(
       imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
       placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
       errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Comment: CircularProgressIndicator appears distorted oval with this plugin

Comment: `return SizedBox(
      width: 560,
      height: 310,
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        // imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        imageUrl: "http://notAvalid.uri",
        // imageUrl: "not a uri at all",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
        // fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );`

errorWidget not show either just an oval loading cirle

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're stacking a `CircularProgressIndicator` widget with a `ClipRect`.

When its first build, you don't have an url and that's the reason why the image isn't showing up. However, as soon as it has content and you rebuild your parent tree (where your `PostItem` widget is inserted) it will refresh with the image but the progress bar won't be gone because doesn't have any condition to prevent its render.

To solve it, the easy way, just add a condition, if you have an url, then you show a `CircularProgressBar` otherwise, a `ClipRect` with your content.

```
(...)    
               Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                     post?.url != null
                      ? const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                      ))
                      : ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        child: Center(
                          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                            image: post.imageUrl,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
(...)
```

If you don't plan to stack items, you can actually remove the `Stack` widget and place it directly within your column. Below is the complete example (without the `Stack`).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
import 'models/post.dart';


class PostItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const PostItem(this.post);

  final Post post;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
      post?.url != null
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
            ))
          : ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              child: Center(
                child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                  placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                  image: post.imageUrl,
                ),
              ),
            ),
      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      Text(
        post.username,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      Text(
        post.text,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, both approaches just have the CircularProgressIndicator widget loading, the images don't load

Comment: I wondering what is the difference between the way I'm doing it and the cookbook example, where's no need for a condition.

Comment: That's probably because you aren't rebuilding your tree for the parent of that particular widget. Can you provide the link for that example? Without a condition in a stateless widget, it won't be possible to make the `CircularProgessBar` because as the name itself explains, it's an immutable widget.

Comment: the link is in the question

Comment: Ok, what's happening in that example, is that the `CircularProgessBar` is still there on the tree but actually below of the image in the `Stack` thats why you can't see it. Since that was only for an example purpose, there's nothing wrong about it, but you probably won't want that to happen (performance wise speaking).
In your example, it's also working just as fine, the difference is that the image is a bit offset with the progress bar, and that makes it a bit visible below it, as you've shown in your gif.